# Generate dynamic columns using pivot

Tags: sql-server

I have  the following query which is always giving the error. Could some body help me
   to resolve this?

> *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword '@stqsql'".*

My code is:

```
  declare @strsql nvarchar(max)
  set @strsql=select merchantid from employee

  select * 
  from 
  (
     Select s.employeeid,
           COUNT(*) as TotCount 
     from Employee s  
     GROUP BY s.employeeid 
  )as a
  pivot (avg(TotCount) for employeeid IN ('+@stqsql+')) AS NoOfRec
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the way you are trying to get dynamic columns does not work. You will have to use something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- this gets the list of values that you want to pivot
select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(merchantid ) 
                    from employee 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

-- since you are use a dynamic list you have to use dynamic sql
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colsPivot + ' from 
             (
                SELECT s.employeeid,
                    COUNT(*) as TotCount
                FROM Employee s
                GROUP BY s.employeeid
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                avg(TotCount)
                for employeeid  in (' + @colsPivot + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```